# OpenStack - keystone did not start

Tags: openstack-keystone

I got this problem during instalation devstack:

```
./stack.sh:1123:start_keystone
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/keystone:578:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/keystone:578 keystone did not start
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2023-07-06-194521.txt for details
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
```

Please Help me with resolving this